# The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

1) Installed and configured Test Agent(2013) using Service Account that has Project Administrator build permissions in TFS in Test Agent machine(Remote Desktop)
2) Installed and configured Test Controller(2013) using same Service Account in Controller machine(Remote Desktop)
3) Established connection between Test Agent and Controller with the same service Account
4) Created successfully a lab environment using the same Service Account in MTM 
5) Created build definition and mapped latest build number to the Test plan in MTM
6) Ran the Test case from MTM but running in to an error with the message "The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required", though service account has access to build drop location
7) Scripted Test methods in Visual Studio 2017 and using TFS 2015. Test Agent and Test Controller are of 2013 version. Service Account and Virtual machines all are in same domain

Comment: Can anyone give me solution for this soon

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with MTM. If you are using vNext build, this issue arises. Please see the Q&A portion in the link below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx